# Solving a simple power grid (flow network)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am looking to model a power grid as a simple graph, and am trying to understand how to solve how much power would travel down each edge.

Here's an example of my "power grid":

[image: Grid example]

On the left I have sources (power generators), on the right I have sinks (power consumers).

There are two differences that I see between this and a regular [Flow Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network):

1. My sinks each have fixed demands, and they can't receive more or less than that
2. I may have an optional vertex (labeled s/t in the diagram) that can represent the "external grid", where I can either send excess power or receive supplemental power as needed.

Ignoring the external-grid vertex for now, I think I could model this by adding a universal source behind all the sources, a universal sink behind all the sinks, and adding both an upper and lower capacity to each edge leading to a sink, where the upper capacity == the lower capacity.

Would that be the best way to model the requirement that each sink has a specific demand?

Of course, it gets trickier if there are two edges leading to a sink, because then I don't know what the capacity of the two edges should be. I guess maybe I could add a fake vertex that the two edges attach to first, and then a single edge between the fake vertex and the sink with that capacity?

And then, I'm not sure how to solve it when I have the s/t vertex. If I work out the solution for the graph without the extra vertex, will that give me the excess or deficiency in the grid, which I could use to then make the vertex a source or sink?

Any thoughts welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess maybe I could add a fake vertex that the two edges attach to first, and then a single edge between the fake vertex and the sink with that capacity?

That's exactly what you should do. So essentially you solved the network construction part all by yourself already.

> And then, I'm not sure how to solve it when I have the s/t vertex.

Just connect it to both your supersource and supersink with infinite capacity.

**Note**: I described the reduction from feasible flow with lower bounds to maximum flow [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23619900/916657), in case you are interested.